# Не соединяется сигнал и слот

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

У класса `QComboBox` есть сигнал, и 2 перегрузки:

```
void currentIndexChanged(int index);
void currentIndexChanged(const QString &);
```

При попытке соединить это дело со слотом класса:

```
public slots:
    ...
    void audioInputSelected(int index);
```

Получаю ошибку

```
ошибка: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QComboBox*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, MainWindow*, void (MainWindow::*)(int))'
connect(ui->inputDevices, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, this, &MainWindow::audioInputSelected);
                                                                                                   ^
```

Соединяю так:

```
connect(ui->inputDevices, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, this, &MainWindow::audioInputSelected);
```

Почему так происходит и как это поправить?

При этом, если использовать старый вариант соединения сигналов и слотов из `Qt4`

```
connect(ui->inputDevices, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(audioInputSelected(int)));
```

то все успешно работает.

Comment: QObject::connect(...) пробовали?

Comment: QWidget, наследник QObject,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Новый синтаксис соединения не умеет (сам) в перегруженные сигналы/слоты. Для того, чтобы соединиться в такой ситуации, надо воспользоваться явным приведением типа (из wiki qt - https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#Overload):

> ```
> connect(mySpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), mySlider, SLOT(setValue(int));
> ```
>
> cannot be simply converted to:
>
> ```
> connect(
>     mySpinBox, &QSpinBox::valueChanged,
>     mySlider, &QSlider::setValue
> )`
> ```
>
> ...because QSpinBox has two signals named valueChanged() with different arguments. Instead, the new code needs to be:
>
> ```
> connect(
>      mySpinBox, static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)> 
>      (&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
>      mySlider, &QSlider::setValue
> );
> ```

Или же воспользоваться `qOverload`, сокращающим этот код -

```
connect(mySpinBox, qOverload<int>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
    mySlider, &QSlider::setValue);
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload